# Popup alignment issue in Left and Right handed touch devices

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, touch, horizontaloffset

I got a problem like in some devices Popup and Menus are opening at wrong places. I analyzed and found that it is happening because Touch enabled devices can be Right-Handed or Left-handed and based on that `HorizontalOffset` property value for Popup and Menu can be different for both of them.

I want to know Is there similar properties also available to take care for Left and Right handed (Touch enabled) devices?